# What is the proper path link to get salary value from Glassdoor website? Please see screenshot

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get the salary text value from Glassdoor salary [website](https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/data-scientist-jobs-SRCH_KO0,14_IP2.htm)
The path link I entered below doesn't seems to be working. Did I enter this correctly?

`salary_estimate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="css-1uyte9r css-hca4ks e1wijj242"]').text`

Below is the screenshot. Please see the blue highlighted area with the target element:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can fetch the salary value from the website you provide and the code below is worked:

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path="/Users/username/Tests/test/chromedriver", options=options)
url = 'https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/data-scientist-jobs-SRCH_KO0,14_IP2.htm'
driver.get(url)
salary_estimate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="css-18034rf e1wijj242"]').text
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this code for me.